# pcre regex translate words not inside but outside string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i have a little problem
i need to translate words from ... to ...
but not inside a string

"hello" must be hello not translate

problem is :
"foo"bar
with pcre reg exp i can find any words inside
a string :

```
  "/^[\"]".$pattern."^[\"]/"
```

but foo i translate rightly
indeed bar it is not translate, because prev character is "
i have to write :

"foo" bar --> a white space after string ... 
same phrases but with a space between string
and other word

can you help me with right regex ?

Comment: So you are trying to match words outside double quotes only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are asking here. I am assuming you want to match words not in quotes `"`?

Here is an example of how you could do this.

```
<?php

$str = <<<STR
"foo"bar
"foo" bar "foo"baz "bar"  foo
STR;

preg_match_all('/[a-z]+(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/i', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
            [1] => bar
            [2] => baz
            [3] => foo
        )
)
```